# continuous assumption to evaluate sequence as a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

$\left\{ a_n\right\} $, does it converge?

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}a_n\ = \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \Rightarrow \frac{0}{0} form $$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}a_n\ = \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}, LHR$$

How can this assumption be made to a sequence that uses integers, without sometimes causing significant effects, for instance:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}sin(\pi n)DNE $, if n is continuous. However,

$\lim_{n \to \infty}sin(\pi n)= 0$, if n is confined to integers.

When can this assumption be made? How can one tell if the function is not as obvious as the above examples?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}sin(\pi n)= 0$ is not true even if confined to the integers. What makes you think that it is?

Comment: any integer multiple of $ \pi $ corresponds to either $\pi$ or $2\pi$ on the unit circle which evaluates sin to 0.

Comment: You're right of course, somehow I missed the $\pi$.Sorry about that.